# AngularJS + Parse.com (Rest API) - Right way to store session token

Tags: angularjs, security, rest, session, parse-platform

I'm working with AngularJS and Parse (through the REST API). I am making a SPA and I have the following problem, all variables are erase when the browser refreshes the page. This means the user's session is closed. I thought of storing the session Token in a cookie to avoid this but If someone is able of retrieve this value, he or she could access all the users information.

What is the most secure way of archiving user's session persistence?
Thanks you all very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sessionStorage. It will not be erased upon refresh.